# How to embed youtube video instead of vimeo video in the plasm simplemodal plugin...?

Tags: jquery, video, youtube, vimeo, video-embedding

the jquery code containing the vimeo player is below

```
$("modal-nofooter").addEvent("click", function(e){
    e.stop();
    var SM = new SimpleModal({"hideFooter":true, "width":710});
        SM.show({
          "title":"Vimeo video",
          "model":"modal",
          "contents":'<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/26198635?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=824571" width="680" height="382" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen allowFullScreen></iframe>'
        });
  })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe change the 'src' attribute of the iframe to the youtube video you want? I'm not familiar with the simplemodal plugin, but right off the top of my head, that sounds about right.

```
$("modal-nofooter").addEvent("click", function(e){
    e.stop();
    var SM = new SimpleModal({"hideFooter":true, "width":710});
        SM.show({
          //You could also probably change the "title" property as well to, say, "Youtube video"
          "title":"Vimeo video",
          "model":"modal",

          /*****      THIS PART HERE, WHERE IS SAYS src   *********/
          "contents":'http://www.youtube.com/embed/abcxyz?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=824571" width="680" height="382" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen allowFullScreen></iframe>'
        });
  })
```

Comment: I changed the src to <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/U74otFbN31Y" width="680" height="382" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen allowFullScreen></iframe>. Its not working.

Comment: It says src="//www...."    Do you have those two forward slashes at the beginning of the URL?  If so, that could be a reason why it's not working.  Remove the "//" before the "www".